# iOS App Crashing on iOS 4.2 but not 4.0, simulator not showing logs

Tags: xcode, ios4, xcode3.2, xcode4

Using XCode 3.2.5 I can run my application on iOS Simulator using the 4.2 SDK. However, it crashes on the following function, more specifically, the presentModalViewController call:

```
- (void)login {
    //check to see if they logged in correctly here
    /*UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Login Failed!" 
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];*/

    [self presentModalViewController:self.accountsViewController animated:YES];
}
```

However, on XCode 4 Dev Preview, I can't even access 4.2 SDK in the Simulator, so I'm forced to use 4.0 SDK. In 4.0, that function works find and as expected. I have two issues:

1. Why is the 4.2 SDK in the Simulator not reporting the reason it crashed in XCode 3.2.5? It used to be that when my app would crash in debugging mode in the Simulator, XCode would pop up the reason. However, it's not anymore.
2. Why would that simple line crash in 4.2 but not 4.0. Could it be the different XCode versions?

Comment: try http://cocoa-nut.de/?p=16

Comment: I don't think it's a memory issue

Answer (score 0):

It was some sort of weird issue between XCode version. I recreated the whole add using solely XCode 3.2.5 and the same exact code now works.